# Angular JS ng-class fails in Internet Explorer (all versions)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

We have a grid of stamp images created with ng-repeat.  Each has an ng-click on it to update a state in the model, and then the class of the stamp should be switched with ng-class and show a different image.

This works perfectly in Firefox and Webkit, but does not work in IE10.  It seems as though no class at all is being applied there, since the initial "clickable" class should show `cursor:pointer` and it doesn't in IE.  Why?

```
<div id="mark-stamp-cells-damaged" title="Mark cells as damaged">
<p>Click on stamp cells you want to mark as unusable/damaged.</p>
<p>Click again to remove selection.</p>
<div class="stamp-sheet-preview">
    <img src="/assets/img/stamps/stamp_sheet_blank.jpg" />
    <ul class="stamp-previews">
        <li ng-repeat="damagedStampSheetCell in damagedStampSheetCells"
            ng-click="updateStampCellState(damagedStampSheetCell)"
            ng-class="{ 'printed': damagedStampSheetCell.state == STAMP_CELL_PRINTED, 'clickable': damagedStampSheetCell.state != STAMP_CELL_PRINTED, 'damaged': damagedStampSheetCell.state == STAMP_CELL_DAMAGED }"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```